# Assigning variable in python confusion

Tags: python

I am trying to understand how a code works. I saw a variable declaration like the one below in the code, but don't understand how that works.

what is the difference between

```
m += 1
```

and

```
1 += m
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if m = 5, then m becomes 6:

```
m += 1
```

means you're incrementing m by 1 (post-increment)

its the same thing as:

```
m = m + 1
```

You can't assign:

```
1 += m
```

that's an illegal operation, the error you should see is:

```
SyntaxError: can't assign to literal
```

Comment: Your answer does not address the original question ("_What is the difference?..._")

Comment: here's the diff: one is legal operation the other is not legal operation lol.

Answer (score 1):

`1 += m` is not a correct syntax. You may get an `Error` something like: `SyntaxError: can't assign to literal`.

In general,

```
m += 1
```

means

`m = m + 1`,

therefore,

`1 += m` 
means

`1 = 1 + m` which is syntactically wrong because you can not assign anything into an integer literal.